# How do you programmatically create a site in liferay?

Tags: java, liferay

I want users to be able to request a site, and upon approval, have that site get created programmatically.

I can't seem to find anything in the API to let me do this.

The request form to the administrator side is trivial, but I would like the administrator to be able to create this site just with the click of a button.

The sites will have different criteria. Some will be public, some restricted, some private, etc.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up the (sadly discontinued) sevencogs-hook sourcecode. This did exactly that, plus it created some pages, users, content etc. through the API. The code is not complex - in fact, it's linear. Easy to read and to follow in the debugger.

I believe it was included in Liferay CE until 6.1.0, so if you want to see it running out of the box, you'll have to download an older version. For documentation purpose this is still fine.